# Azure ARM - Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I am going to configure created azure VM (for example, install role, initialize new hdd disk etc). I see that there is a new feature **Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts** in azure ARM. As per documantation I created **Managed Identity** in my subscription, give **Contributor** permissions to newly created **Managed Identity**, on **Subscription** level. then I developed below ARM template using **Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts** feature. code pasted below. I want to paste this code into my ARM template for VM deployment.Question is if I will be able to use this approach to perform scripts like: installing role on the OS level, like IIS or WSUS, configure HDD etc...

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "'John Dole'"
        },
        "utcValue": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[utcNow()]"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
            "apiVersion": "2019-10-01-preview",
            "name": "runPowerShellInlineWithOutput",
            "location": "westeurope",
            "kind": "AzurePowerShell",
            "identity": {
                "type": "userAssigned",
                "userAssignedIdentities": {
                    "/subscriptions/SubID/resourceGroups/RGname/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/MI-ARMdeployment": {}
                }
            },
            "properties": {
                "forceUpdateTag": "[parameters('utcValue')]",
                "azPowerShellVersion": "3.0",
                "scriptContent": "
        $output = 'hello'
         Write-Output $output",
       "arguments": "",
                "timeout": "PT1H",
                "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess",
                "retentionInterval": "P1D"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes (with some hacks), but its not meant for that. Its meant for provisioning\configuring Azure level resources, not things inside of the VM.

You have [DSC extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/dsc-overview) and [script extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows) for that (available for both windows\linux).

Comment: ok, got it, I found thet I can use CSE from ARM template --> https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-custom-script-windows/azuredeploy.json, in section related to "CustomScriptExtension" I see params like: _artifactsLocation, _artifactsLocationSasToken. I dont want to use external links for downloading ps1 scripts, I would prefer rather storage account, or pasting inline script into the ARM json file. Is it possible to use storage account to store ps1 files, or paste script into the json file?

Comment: both are possible. with the storage account you can use the `_artifactsLocationSasToken` to protect the file, pasting inline also works, but is probably not really feasible